# Connecting to a local MS SQL instance - User Must change password at next login

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services, local-database

I am working on an Azure Mobile Apps backend service, which I am trying to connect to a local MS SQL database, as describe [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#howto-sqlexpress-setup). I have followed all the steps, except I am using 2016 rather than 2014.

If I follow the Microsoft tutorial exactly, everything works fine. I am not sure what the environment variable is about, as I don't reference it anywhere, but anyway, when I run my app, I get the following output:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
2016-06-19T09:37:39.331Z - error: Error occurred during table initialization ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'azuremobile'.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed.
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:378:25)
    at Connection.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Connection.processLogin7Response (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:672:16)
    at Connection.message (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1082:21)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:519:45)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:439:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:166:7)
```

This seems to be because of the setting that is shown below, "User Must change password at next login"? [image]

However, If I change the password, or delete and recreate the login but unchecking that feature. I get this:

> error: Error occurred during table initialization ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'azuremobile'.

I am possibly getting the password wrong, but I have tried this 6 times now. Is there a way I can check the password or anything else I can do to get my node project to login to my local SQL db?

Comment: Most probably because password policy is on you might have locked the password? You can try finding this user in database users and try unlocking the account and retrying.

Answer (score 1):

There is an environment variable called `SQLCONNSTR_MS_TableConnectionString` - this contains the connection string for the SQL Database - which includes the username and password of the SQL user that you use to connect to the database.

Remedy:

1) Set the password of the SQL user

2) Uncheck the "user must change password at next login"

3) Update the environment variable `SQLCONNSTR_MS_TableConnectionString` to include the password you just set

4) Restart your node backend